# jsPDF + html2canvas in HTA/IE11

Tags: promise, internet-explorer-11, jspdf, html2canvas, hta

I want to generate a PDF from a hta file (http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11"). Append to child is working like a charme. However it doesn't work with jsPDF...  Any help appreciated!

Scripts included:

```
<script src="polyfill.min.js"></script><!-- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7/dist/polyfill.min.js -->
<script src="jspdf.js"></script><!-- https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/src/jspdf.js -->
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script><!-- https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js -->
```

DIV to print:

```
<div class ="print" id="print">
<h3>print!</h3>
<input type="button" id="pdfPrint" value="PDF erstellen" />
</div>
```

Script Code:

```
        document.getElementById('pdfPrint').addEventListener('click', function() {

        html2canvas(document.getElementById("print")).then(function(canvas) {
        // document.getElementById("print").appendChild(canvas);

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(img,'JPEG',20,20);
        pdf.save('Testung.pdf');

                }

            });

        });
```

Comment: Bad polyfill maybe?

Comment: Thanks so far. You're right and meanwhile I was able to find a polyfill that fits, but I'm still facing some issues under ie11... I've updated the code above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a test with your code. And I've found that there will be ReferenceError: 'jsPDF' is undefined in IE11.

The key point is the reference of jsPDF. You should replace your jsPDF script with latest one:https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js

Then the running result is as the capture below: [image: running result]

Comment: AWESOME!!!! You made my day :) I've noticed there are dozends of scripts each more or less compatible. I had the same issue with  PROMISE- THX for the right jsPDF- it's working now!